# Laravel querying data through a pivot table

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have a table called 'projects' and a table called 'tags'. These 2 are connected through a pivot table named 'project_tag' so for example like this:

There is 1 record in the projects table with project_id 1

then in the 'project_tag' table there is this :

```
project_id 1 and tag_id 1
```

and tag_id 1 is "sometag" for example

Now my problem is I want to query all the projects that has "sometag" as name in the tags table.
Is there a way to do this? Or should I work with the id's instead of the tag values?

What my models look like:

Project model:

```
 public function tags()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Tag')->withTimestamps();
    }
```

Tag model:

```
public function projects()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Project');
    }
```

I am a bit lost in my database structure :) I am fairly new to laravel

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To query projects by certain tags you ca do like this:

```
// Get projects by a single tag
$tag = 'mytag';

Project::whereHas('tags', function ($q) use ($tag) {
    $q->whereName($tag);
    // or $q->whereSlug($tag);
})->get();

// Get projects by multiple tags
$tags = ['mytag', 'othertag', 'iamtag'];

Project::whereHas('tags', function ($q) use ($tags) {
    $q->whereIn('name', $tags);
})->get();
```

Or you can query projects from pivot table like this:

```
// Get projects by a single tag
$tag_id = 1;

Project::whereIn('id', function($q) use ($tag_id) {
    $q->select('project_id')->from('project_tag')->where('tag_id', $tag_id);
})->get();

// Get projects by multiple tags
$tag_ids = [1, 2, 3];

Project::whereIn('id', function($q) use ($tag_ids) {
    $q->select('project_id')->from('project_tag')->whereIn('tag_id', $tag_ids);
})->get();
```

Comment: Problem is I don't want to work with tag_id I want to work with the name that is stored in the tag table

Comment: @Cruzito In the first example above you can change `id` to whatever column you want such as `name` or `slug`

Comment: It says undefined variable tag

Comment: May bad, I forgot to add `use` statement, see edited answer

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your model is called **Project** and your project-tag relationship is called **tags()**, this should work out for you:

```
    Project::whereHas('tags', function ($query) {
        $query->where('name', 'like', '%sometag%');
    })->get();
```

Comment: does it have to be formatted like this `%sometag%`? Because I have a variable where the tag is stored in

Comment: No, I'm just using your example. You can do like this `$query->where('name', 'like', "%{$varNameHere}%");`.

Comment: Where do you have this variable? Can you paste the code.

Comment: It's the $varNameHere variable I changed it to my variable and it says undefined but when I do dd($tag); it shows the variable so I dont know wht it says undefined

Comment: You have to tell the anonymous function to use it.

Comment: `Project::whereHas('tags', function ($query) use ($tag) {
            $query->where('name', 'like', "%{$tag}%");
        })->get();`

Answer (score 0):

Adding to what @TheFallen has said your models should look like this

```
class Tag extends Model
{
    /**
     * Get all of the tags project
     */
    public function projects()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Project');
    }
}

class Project extends Model
{
    /**
     * Get all of the project's tag
     */
    public function tags()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Tag');
    }
}
```

Then you can do this

```
   Project::whereHas('tags', function ($query) {
        $query->where('name', 'like', '%sometag%');
    })->get();
```

Comment: It looks a bit different, if you're interested I can post how it looks with me and you can check it out?