# how to get data from a pivot table in a query at a controller

Tags: laravel

I have created a query in function at the controller where I want to get data from a pivot table based on the value sent using jquery.how can i create a function to get the values of the id associated with the selected house id in the controller.i have tried this but i get an error

```
 $rentalcategoryhouses=Rental_house::whereIn('rentalcat_id',$rentalcategorydetails['catids'])
            ->with('housetags')->where('tag_id',$data['rentaltag'])->get();
```

the housetags here is the belongstoMany function in the house model that associates the houses with the tags.

```
 function housetags(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(Rental_tags::class,'rentalhouse_tags','rental_id','tag_id');
}
```

i want to get all the houses associated with the specific tag_id using a query in the controller.

Answer (score 0):

this answer here solved my bug [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37525939/laravel-querying-data-through-a-pivot-table)